# Get a string using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to capture a string that is between two commas. I created the following code:

```
Regex.Match(forReg, @"\,([^,]*)\,");
```

the forReg string will look like this

```
forReg = "123456,x,NULL"
```

Where x is an integer less than 999.

The first problem is I'm not sure how to use the string that I've captuered using Regex.Match and the second problem is I'm not even sure if I've done the Regex code correctly. I've looked up several threads with similar issues but can't seem to make any more progress.

Comment: The regex looks right by me. This has some examples that might help you:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Comment: You don’t need to escape commas though, so `",([^,]*),"` would be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this worked

```
            Match match = Regex.Match(forReg, @"\,([^,]*)\,");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                string age = match.Groups[1].Value;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the captured match by using the [Match.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, and secondly you do not need to escape the comma's inside your regular expression because it is not a character of special meaning.

```
String forReg = "123456,77,NULL";
Match match   = Regex.Match(forReg, @",([^,]*),");

if (match.Success) {
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); //=> "77"
}
```